# How to substitute WebResource with static file in ASP.NET 3.5

Tags: javascript, asp.net, scriptmanager, webresource.axd, scriptresource.axd

How can I substitute resources which are exposed through the WebResource for particular page?

I have following code in the page markup that perfectly works for the ScriptResource but not for the WebResource:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="Scriptmanager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
                Path="~/MyMicrosoftAjaxWebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
                Path="~/MyMicrosoftAjax.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Actually I need to substitute the WebForms.js script.

---

Related resources:
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETAjaxScriptCombiningAndMovingScriptResourceaxdsToStaticScripts.aspx

Comment: I have exactly the same question. Currently I have different versions comming from Mono and Windows.
Did you find an answer?